# npm takes a lot of time to run commandes

Tags: npm, npm-start

hi guys I'm working with npm for more than 1 year and in the resent month it takes a lot of time to actually run commandes or create react-app . I tried to fix the npm-cash or delet it .is it good to delete the cash and what is the impact of that ? but that didn't work .is it a problem with terminal or windows?
how can I make running commands faster?
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The NPM cache is designed to speed things up. Clearing cache will only slow it down.

The slowdown can be a number of things, you will need to debug further. Does the slowdown happen while modules are being downloaded off the internet, does it happen while a build process is running, or during disk I/O?

It's more than likely that the issue is outside of NPM. You might be running out of disk space, some other process could be hogging up memory, or there might be network related issues.

Comment: i checked the network and it's fine ,yea I thow also the what I did is wrong and reinstall node with npm and that didn't fix anything .it happened even there is anything running and when I start new react-app it takes some time .also when I start testing any app it takes more than a min and some times more than 5 mins

Comment: Check Task Manager (Windows), Activity Monitor (OSX), htop (Linux) while running a command to see if any of your resources max out - CPU, Memory. You might need additional third party utilities to monitor disk and network usage too. Find out which resource is maxing and that's your bottleneck.